# Check if user have set security Question

Tags: soql, security

Is there a soql that system admin can execute to list users who have set **security question** during their past logins?

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you want to check for this? What purpose would it serve?

Comment: @sfdcfox my usecase is to do password change for BULK users.Many of them use a common email address.So reset password from application is not an option

Comment: @sfdcfox Below code works fine and prompts user to change the pwd upon login ONLY if he/she has not set security Q in past

List<Id> userIds = new List<Id> { 'xxxxx','cccc','ddddd'};
List<User> users = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE Id IN :userIds];
for(User u : users) {
    System.setPassword(u.Id, 'yyyyy'); 
}
update users;

Therefore we are trying to identify those users through SOQL.Hope I am able to explain you my use case.If you have a clean solution that would be great

Answer (score 0):

In Salesforce, there isn't a direct way to fetch the information about whether a user has set a security question during their past logins. This is because Salesforce does not provide a specific field in the User object to store the status of the security question set by the user